# xml format for creating cost centre in tally

Tags: tally

What is the xml format for creating a single new cost centre in tally under Primary group.

For eg. XML tags to Create a Group named 'My Debtors' under 'Sundry Debtors' is as below:

```
<!--XML tags to create a Group named My Debtors under Sundry Debtors-->
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
            </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <GROUP NAME="My Debtors" ACTION="Create">
                        <NAME.LIST>
                            <NAME>My Debtors</NAME>
                        </NAME.LIST>
                        <PARENT>Sundry Debtors</PARENT>
                        <ISSUBLEDGER>No</ISSUBLEDGER>
                        <ISBILLWISEON>No</ISBILLWISEON>
                        <ISCOSTCENTRESON>No</ISCOSTCENTRESON>
                    </GROUP>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it finally:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
            </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <COSTCENTRE NAME="NewCostCentre">
                        <NAME>NewCostCentre</NAME>
                    </COSTCENTRE>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```